# According to Catholic scholars, whose home was Jesus stopping by while visiting Capernaum, in Mk 2: 1?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-mark

We read in Mk 2: 1

When he returned to Capernaum after some days, it was reported that he was at home(NRSVCE)

A few days later, when Jesus again entered Capernaum, the people heard that he had come home (NIV)

In day-to-day English, that would mean Jesus was visiting his own home in Capernaum. But some argue that it was the home of Zebedee , father of James and John that the Lord  was visiting. My question therefore is: According to Catholic scholars, whose home was Jesus stopping by  while visiting Capernaum, in Mk 2:1?

Comment: 'The house' (Greek Literal) does not equate to 'at home'. It merely states 'indoors' as opposed to 'outdoors'. Spiritually, it evokes the concept of the body of the assembly, the church. Headship and the body, in union. The saying avoids stating _whose_ house it was, so that the concept of _God's house_ may be evoked.